# Reading a file without preventing other processes from reading it at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, timer, filesystemwatcher

I'm making a little app in C#/.NET that watch for the creation of a file and when it is created it gets its content, parse it and write it in another file.

Everything is working fine so far. But the problem is : there's another process that watch for this file as well. My process is only READING the file while the second one reads it and then DELETES it.

My application is making its job but when it reads the file, the other process can't read it and totally crashes (Not made by me and don't have the sources to fix it).

My application is running very fast and other open the files for a very little time to get the content and put it in a variable so it could close the file faster and then parse the content of the file which is in the variable.

I clearly don't know how but I'd like to be able to read the file and let the other read the file at the same time without any hiccups. Is it possible? I still think that there will be a problem about the fact that the file is being deleted after the other app is done parsing it...

Any suggestions or ideas?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It sounds like the problem isn't reading, it's that the other process tries to modify (delete) the file while it's locked for read access. This whole setup sounds very sketchy, because you are just hoping that your process notices the file first. Any number of factors could make this extremely unreliable.

Comment: Do you have control over the process that _creates_ the file? If so, have it create two files, then read the one not used by the process you have no control over.

Comment: @jamietre : I'm aware of the sketchy factor, don't worry about it ;) But it's only to gather real usage data to use with the new version I'm developing right now. So reliability isn't very important.

@Michael: No I don't have any control, if I had then I wouldn't be making a program to duplicate the data :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KISS:  Can you have the file created in a location which the first program isn't looking at, but your software is - and when you are done processing it you then move it to the current location where the first program *is* looking?

Otherwise:
You are going to have contention since it's going to be a race to see which process actually "notices" the file first and begins working.

I'm assuming you also don't have any control over the process creating the file?

In that case you might look at [PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx) or [PauseSp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/pausep.aspx) - if you can control the other process by suspending it until you are ready for it (done with the file) then that might be viable.  Not sure how robust this would be.

There's also still the potential race condition of "noticing" the file and performing an action (whatever it is) - keeping the other process paused perpetually until you want it to run (or killing it and starting it) is the only completely deterministic way to achieve what you want within the constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file as follows to ensure **you** don't lock it from other processes:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) 
{
  // do your stuff
}
```

But if the **other** process is trying to open it in exclusive mode, it won't help and it will still crash. There's no way to deal with that other than fixing the code for the other process.

Comment: It would probably be better to just `var file = File.ReadAllBytes(path)` so the file isn't open during the operation (unless there are write operations).

Comment: @Erik Phillips - Good suggestion, however, the MSDN page doesn't mention what mode the file is opened in, from what I can see (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx). So I did it this way to ensure we didn't lock the file from other potential readers. If you know somewhere it's documented that File.ReadAllBytes uses FileShare.ReadWrite for the share mode, then I agree with you.

Comment: The other process seems to open the file in exclusive mode. So whatever I try makes the other app crashes... I'm starting to think it's almost -impossible- to do...

Comment: @dcp, it's not documented, but Telerik's JustDecompile shows File.ReadAllBytes as opening with FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, and FileShare.Read.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an NTFS drive (which is very likely), then you can create a hard-link to the file. Essentially, this duplicates the file without actually creating a duplicate. You can read the file with the hard-link. The other process can delete the file, which will only remove their link to the file. This will leave the file in place for you to read. When your program is done reading the file, it can delete the hard-link, and the file system will see that both links have been deleted, and it will delete the file itself.

This can be done from the [command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097%28WS.10%29.aspx) with

```
fsutil hardlink create <NewFileName> <ExistingFileName>
```

Or you can [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=CreateHardLink&namespace=%5BAll%5D) the [`CreateHardLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363860%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function in the Windows API.

Comment: Very neat solution - there's still the race condition though - you can't guarantee whatever you have creating the hard link is going to occur before the original program "notices" the file and begins it's read/delete cycle.

Comment: @Chris B - That is true. I am assuming that all of the architectual decisions given in the OP were fixed and unchanging. Clearly, the basic design is itself flawed, and the correct solution would be to change it if possible, as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create another empty zero bytes file called .reading file which has the same name but extension "reading" to it. Then once first process is done reading the file, rename .reading to .done and the second process can check .done files and delete the original file,since both .done and original file have same name but different extensions ?.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashant's response gave me the inspiration for this, and it's very similar, but I believe will solve your problem.

If the other process must match a certain filename pattern

- Rename the file to something that
  won't match first, a very cheap/fast
  operation
- Rename it back when finished

If it matches every file in a given folder

- Move it to another folder (also a very cheap operation in most filesystems)
- Move it back when finished.

If the other process had already locked your file (even for read) then your process would fail, and you can make that graceful. If not you should be safe.

There is still a race condition possibility, of course, but this should be much safer than what you are doing.